# $wp_filesystem return null

Tags: php, wordpress

Глобальная переменная $wp_filesystem в WordPress возвращает null. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Её инициализировать надо. Поищите в интернете, я дороге и не могу подробно ответить.

Comment: Вот хороший пример использования: https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/08/wordpress-filesystem-api-the-right-way-to-operate-with-local-files/

Comment: спасибо но проблема была в другом уже решилось